# PSU Module for Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: power-supply, raspberry-pi, mains

I need to build a small circuit to control some relays where I need to power a Raspberry Pi Zero from mains power using the GPIO pins.

I saw this module: Mean Well IRM-05-5 5VDC 1A 5W.

Is this module suited for the job? Do I need to add more elements to do filtering/regulation or I can just connect the mains directly to AC input and then DC out to Raspberry Pi GPIO?

Are there more better modules or more "professional"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not suited. Raspberry Zero power specs recommend at least 1.2A supply for the Zero itself, plus whatever the relays and other circuitry uses.

Besides that model is supposed to be soldered on PCB. It would not be very safe or professional to connect it in any other way than soldering it on a PCB.

Comment: Something like this one Mean Well RS-25-5 would be a better solution then?

Comment: I don't know what is better in your case. I just keep thinking why you want something where you must work with mains voltage wiring as that is dangerous. What's wrong with using a ready made 5V wall adapter, like the ones you use to charge your phone.

Comment: Because this will part of circuit to control an Audio Power Amplifier. And that amplifier already has a mains IEC mains socket, i don't is an elegant solution to have another transformer coming to amplifier case